# Menus are not visible

Tags: interface

I am new to Blender and I just got ver 2.80 on redhat 7.1

When I open Blender I see the outline of menus but I am not seeing any text. the box is completely transparent.  Even why I close Blender there is a message box outline but nothing inside it.  any ideas on what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your hardware meets the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender 2.80. The section about GPU requirements is particularly important.

> **Supported Graphics Cards**
>
> These requirements are for basic Blender operation, rendering using
>   the GPU requires slightly different [requirements](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware). Always make sure to
>   install the latest drivers from the graphics card manufacturer
>   website.
>
> - NVIDIA: GeForce 200 and newer, Quadro Tesla architecture and newer, with NVIDIA drivers (list of all [GeForce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce#GeForce_200_series_and_300_series) and [Quadro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Quadro#Quadro_FX_(with_CUDA_and_OpenCL,_but_no_Vulkan)) GPUs)
> - AMD: GCN 1st gen and newer ([list of all AMD GPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units))
> - Intel: Haswell and newer ([list of all Intel GPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units))
> - macOS: version 10.12 or newer with supported hardware

If your hardware meets the minimum requirements, you're likely having issues with your graphics driver and it has to be updated.

Comment: the system is running a Quadro FX 4800 so we are good there I need to update the driver it is using an older driver.